# I'm trying to create a program that creates anagrams from a string of words

Tags: python, anagram

I'm new to python - so from a list of predetermined words jumble the letters and return the jumbled letters.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We're not a code writing service, so please show what you tried before asking a question - thanks!

Comment: @Zapp, please read the advice for new users under the "help" link at the top of the page.  You should provide a LOT more detail and also demonstrate that you have at least attempted to think about how to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> word_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
>>> shuffled_list = [''.join(random.sample(s,len(s))) for s in word_list]
>>> shuffled_list
['pepal', 'abanan', 'raoegn']
```

Comment: Hi @Zapp if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the question? It depends if you want to get words that actually make sense or just every kind of anagram. For the first one, you would probably need an dictionary API. For the second one, you would just have to scramble the words in every possible way.

Comment: The question is can you help me create a program that uses words from a created list in python eg. list_anagram [apple, banana, orange] and jumbles the letters for each word and then returns each of the words as an anagram.  If that makes sense?

Comment: You will need to write the program yourself. For each word in a list, you want to get exactly one anagram?